# why are buttons not turning off?

Tags: jquery

I have a piece of code below where it contains buttons A-Z. Each button can be turned on and turned off.

```
<?php
    $a = range("A","Z");
?>

<?php
        $i = 1;
        foreach($a as $key => $val){
            if($i%7 == 1) echo"<tr><td>";
            echo"<input type=\"button\" onclick=\"btnclick(this);\" value=\"$val\" id=\"answer".$val."\" name=\"answer".$val."Name\" class=\"answerBtns answers answerBtnsOff\">";      
            if($i%7 == 0) echo"</td></tr>";
            $i++;
        }
    ?>
```

Below is the code where I am trying to turn on and off the correct buttons but the problem is that it is not turning off the buttons.

```
var answers = '#answer'+btn;
$('.answers.answerBtnsOn').find('answerBtnsOn').addClass('answerBtnsOff');
```

Now if I change the last line of code to code below:

```
$('.answerBtnsOn').find('answerBtnsOn').addClass('answerBtnsOff');
```

then it works but the problem is that all my buttons have the class ".answerBtnsOn", I only want the buttons within the "answers" variable to be turned off.

So I changed the code to this:

```
$('.answerBtnsOn', answers).addClass('answerBtnsOff');
```

But it doesn't turn off any buttons, why won't it turn off any buttons which are turned on?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this

```
$('.answers.answerBtnsOn').removeClass('answerBtnsOn').addClass('answerBtnsOff');
```

or

```
$('.answers').filter('.answerBtnsOn').removeClass('answerBtnsOn').addClass('answerBtnsOff');
```

In your code you're never removing the `on` class just adding the `off` on top of it

Comment: Problem with this is that it turns off all buttons which contains '.answerBtnsOn' (I mean every single button) I only want the buttons which contains '.answerBtnsOn' in the "answers" variable to be turned off.

Answer (score 1):

Try `toggleClass()`.  It looks like you are just adding the class rather than changing it or removing the previous class.

For full documentation, see the jQuery website: http://api.jquery.com/toggleClass/

As stated:

```
$('#foo').toggleClass(className, addOrRemove);
```

Is the equivalent to:

```
if (addOrRemove) {
  $('#foo').addClass(className);
} else {
  $('#foo').removeClass(className);
}
```

So within your code, I would write:

```
$('.answerBtnsOn', answers).toggleClass('answerBtnsOn');
```

Unless of course your button off state is different to the default state at which it has not been pressed, which would be very strange for a button.  Either way, you can toggle both classes very easily with this function.

Comment: I have tried it but it hasn't worked, it still doesn't turn off buttons